# Is it possible to disable closing a tab with cmd/ctrl+w on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I have this problem in which I will accidentally close a pinned tab with cmd+w.

Is there a way to disable closing a tab with the keyboard shortcut and to only make it so that you have to right click + close in order to close the tab?

I'm using Macos but I would like an answer for Windows, MacOs and Linux.

Comment: Not natively, you'll need an extension such as ShortKeys.

Comment: What OS? On Mac you can do it in the keyboard control panel. See https://superuser.com/questions/1282076/how-do-i-remove-or-replace-a-mac-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: @Tetsujin Does this allow for disabling cmd/ctrl+w for pinned tabs only, whilst allowing it for non-pinned tabs?

Comment: Only if there's a specific menu command for each. Look at the answer, it fully explains how the structure works.

Comment: ShortKeys didn't work for me, but https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/keyboard-shortcuts/lplcmnhgijkkmflbmhabnccgelffpnog did

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can use AutoHotKey to catch Crtl-W and require confirmation or ignore, etc. AFAIK there is no way to do it for just pinned tabs. Here's a script I am using. I am not very proficient with AutoHotKey, so there may be a better way to do it. There are other tools like AutoIt as well.

```
Global bflag
SetTitleMatchMode,2 
bflag = 0
;
; script to verify cntrl-w tab deletion in browers
; 
;#IfWinActive, Notepad
;#IfWinActive, Chrome
GroupAdd browser, Chrome
GroupAdd browser, Firefox
GroupAdd browser, Vivaldi
GroupAdd browser, Opera
GroupAdd browser, Edge
; for testing
; GroupAdd browser, Notepad

#IfWinActive ahk_group browser

^w::
   SplashTextOn, 1000, 50, Delete, press DELETE to confirm or escape
   Suspend, ON
   Input, SingleKey, L1 T1, {Del}{Escape}
   SplashTextOff
   IfInString, ErrorLevel, Del
     Send ^w
   Suspend, OFF
Return

; End
```