# override mac command + number keyboard shortcuts

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to have command + 1 open chrome from everywhere.

I created a workflow using the automator to open chrome, and added the shortcut to both all apps and terminal
[image]

still, when I'm on most applications, including terminal, pressing command + 1 does not open chrome. For example in the terminal it focuses the first tab instead.

how do I override it?

Comment: You'll have to find every app that uses that command & replace them one by one - **if** they have it as a menu command. Most don't. Why not just pick a shortcut that's not going to fight everything in the system? BTW, typing 'chrome' into an app's shortcut list is not going to do anything at all.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1282092/347380

Comment: @Tetsujin 1. I created a workflow in automator called `chrome` and it does work when not in apps that override it. The reason I choose the command key + number to switch between windows is it's the easiest key to reach, and it's what I do most. So if as you said most apps don't have it as menu command, how do I go about it?

Comment: You don't. If it's not in the menu it's not replaceable. Cmd/[num] is a global. Many apps use it to switch tabs, but it's not in the menu. Pick another trigger. Using any simple Cmd/single key is going to conflict with something, somewhere. You're just making life harder for yourself.